# What is the meaning of "Root Access Required"?

Tags: rooting, root-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I root my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

what is root in android OS, some time i read rooted OS uprooted phone what it mean and recently i read "Root Access Required" on an android article.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone) should tell you everything you need to know (and a bit more) - [How do I root my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

Comment: @Matt H: thanks a lot, how to check weather i have rooted my phone or not ?

Comment: If you did not root it then it isn't rooted. Unless you bought it used, then it is possible, but doubtful.

Comment: As Matt pointed out, you can find your answers at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone